# JavaScript header file necessary?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple .js files under one namespace, suppose my namespace is `foo`, in each file I have codes like below:

In file `utils.js`

```
(function() {

    window.foo = window.foo || {};
    foo.utils = foo.utils || {};
    foo.bar = foo.bar || {};

    var utils = foo.utils;
    var bar = foo.bar;

    utils.helper1 = function(abc) {

        var xyz = bar(abc);
        ...
    }

})();
```

Basically in each js file, I want to have code like `var utils = foo.utils` so I don't have to write `foo.utils` every time. But then I have to write `foo.utils = foo.utils || {};` at the top because utils.js may not be loaded yet.

I think one way to solve this is to have a header file and make sure it's always loaded first, it basically declares all public functions under my namespace like below:

```
window.foo = windown.foo || {};
foo.bar = {};
foo.baz = {};
foo.utils = {};
```

Is there better way? I don't want to have to ensure the load sequence of my js files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you already know the choices.

1. **Script load order is not controlled.**  You make sure that every single file initializes each object in the namespace before using it (as your example does).
2. **One file that is guaranteed to be loaded first initializes the namespaces.**  You put the namespace initialization code into one file and you make sure that file is loaded first.  The other files then know that the namespaces are already initialized so they don't have to do it.

> Is there better way?

No, not really.  There are no shortcuts beyond these choices.  If you don't want to force any particular load order, then you need the boilerplate to initialize a namespace before you assign to it.

There are other hybrid choices such as you define a function that lets you assign to a namespace and the function will create the namespace for you if it doesn't already exist.  But then of course, you have to make sure that function is already loaded first too so it doesn't really save you much over the above options.

Comment: 3. You declare the variables inline in the HTML before the JavaScript insertions (probably in a header file). This is not an ideal solution though, because it is transmitted every time a page is loaded (no cache) and it mixes HTML with JavaScript.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 - I guess that is technically an option, but then you have to copy that code into every single HTML file and it is still order sensitive as you have to copy it before the relevant scripts are loaded.  And, if you have to make a change, you then have to modify every single HTML file. I guess I don't see how that's any better than the option 2 we already have.

Comment: Interesting, I don't have industrial experience in JavaScript so I thought there might be some consensus solution for this or some JavaScript magic I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: @Arch1tect - In most cases, it makes sense to make each JS file just take care of initializing any namespace that it's going to assign to.  Then you have more freedom to include individual JS files as needed and each one is more self contained.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't think this is only a theoretical solution. Usually you are using a server-side language in which you can easily concat the files (PHP, Java, Perl..). Then, you have one header file which is included  everywhere (the doctype, meta data etc. needs to be also in every file). Of course you need to include the JavaScript dependencies afterwards. The best solution in my opinion is the usage of a JavaScript build process (Grunt, Gulp, etc) to concat all the files in the correct order.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 - A server-side JS build process that combines scripts in a particular order is one perfectly fine means of controlling the order in which the scripts are run.  A server-side template engine that includes sub-files inline is another perfectly fine means of controlling the order in which the scripts are run.

Comment: @Arch1tect - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.